# How to create an index on a Time_Stamp column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table with over 2 million rows, and I am trying to Query for records for specific times from my Time_Stamp column.

As expected, the Query takes a very long time to execute.

I have read that the best way to optimize this type of query is to index the time_stamp, but I have not been able to find methods on how to do this.

My main questions are as follows:

- How do I create an index on my Time_Stamp column to optimize my query?
- I am one of several users who connects in to this database, so would the creation of an index affect the other users and their queries in any way?

Comment: Just like with any other column type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an index with create index

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name)
```

For second question   .  adding an index   can change the query  optimization do the fact that the index are evaluated  for find the best scan strategy  by the database engine  for this you can take a look ad this chapter on mysql docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am writing data to my table every second.  Will the effect of the Index be noticeable?

Comment: @Gary add `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` and `LOCK=NONE` to the above statement, to ensure that concurrent writes and reads are allowed to continue while the index is being built. Prior to 5.6, these aren't available and the table will be locked while the index is built.  Reads and writes will stall and wait.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So I had an issue with my LabView (which feeds MySQL) freezing when I made a query from another client computer.  I have not yet added the `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` and `LOCK=NONE` to my statement.  Do you think this will fix the freezing?  Also, do both of these commands go at the end of the statement above?

Comment: @Gary this should either eliminate the stall, or it will immediately return an error (and change nothing) if the server has a reason why it can't be done.  Yes, you should be able tk just add these to the `CREATE INDEX` although I usually use this form: `ALTER TABLE t1 ADD KEY (c1), LOCK=NONE, ALGORITHM=INPLACE;`... from memory, I don't think `CREATE INDEX` expects the commas but `ALTER TABLE` does. Otherwise, the statments have the equivalent effect.